# Firebreath and CURL- Error on refresh

Tags: curl, firebreath

I am using CURL with firebreath to download images and my code is like below.

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallbacks);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, api_url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "SERVICE");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);

    response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(response != CURLE_OK) 
    {
        _error = curl_easy_strerror(response);
    }
```

It works correctly, if I am waiting till the process completes. If I refresh the page during download and or once called the curl_easy_perform(curl), it causes an access violation error and plugin crash.. How to handle this...

I tried to call curl_easy_cleanup(curl) on destructor and it didnn't help.

please help....

Comment: what is the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Another question; is this on the main thread or a secondary thread? From the looks of things curl_easy_perform is a blocking call, and you *must not* block the main thread